# Restrict Access of A Product based on few criterias

Tags: odoo

Goal:
Show all products to all users who have access rights to the purchase module.
However **besides** the above rule show only products who have value 'secfab' in the reference field to the users who created the same product.

Problem:
I tried using access records but my logic to build it is weak and I need help.

Case 1:
[('default_code','!=','secfab'),('created_id','=',user.id)]

If I code this then I only get one record and other records are not shown.

Case 2:
['|',('default_code','!=','secfab'),('created_id','=',user.id)]

If I code this then I only all the records and I am not able to achieve privacy that I wanted.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second case seems to be correct, except the clause for filtering on the creator looks misspelled. This typo could cause the rule to match all records, because the condition on the non-existing field `created_id` cannot be verified. Shouldn't it be:

```py
['|', ('default_code', '!=', 'secfab'), ('create_uid', '=', user.id)]
```

which translates to "*show all products that don't have `secfab` as code, plus all products, that the user created, regardless of their code*", and seems to do what you want?

`create_uid` is one of the 4 fields automatically added by the system to all models that have `_log_access` set to `True`, which is the default. This is explained in the [OpenERP technical memento](http://doc.openerp.com/memento/) and in the [special fields documentation](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/03_modules_2.html#predefined-fields).

Comment: the above solution had a small issue which made other products not listed so this solution worked ['|','|',('default_code','=',False),('default_code','!=','secfab'),('create_uid','=',user.id)]